# Fields_for with permitted attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form in Rails that looks like this psuedo code:

```
<%= form_for :project do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :rewards do |r| %>
    <%= r.text_field :title %>
```

I have everything working except when I submit the form I get an error: `Unpermitted parameter: rewards`. What should my permissions look like in the Project controller?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the nested attributes as a hash option with an array of permitted attributes:

```
require(:project).permit(
  :foo, :bar, 
  rewards_attributes: [:title]
)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
require(:project).permit(
  :foo, :bar, 
  { rewards_attributes: [:title] }
)
```

Comment: I defined params as `params.require(:project).permit(:user_id, :title, :format, :charge_occurrence, :body, rewards_tiers_attributes: [:min_amount, :body])` but I'm still getting the same error `Unpermitted parameter: rewards_tiers`. My params look like 
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user_id"=>"3", "project"=>{"title"=>"Bill's podcast", "format"=>"pod", "charge_occurrence"=>"monthly", "body"=>"The body", "rewards_tiers"=>{"min_amount"=>"$1", "body"=>"Doin stuff"}}}`